# regex match any until certain string TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

I am trying to match certain string it goes like this:

```
apn xxxxx
      blah blah blah
      blah -blah blah blah -blah -blah blah-blah-blah
      blah-blah
      blah blah blah-1 blah-blah BLAH
      blah blah BLAH-2 blah-blahBLAH
      blah blah BLAH-3 blah-blahBLAH
      blah blah BLAH-4 blah-blahBLAH
      blah-blah blah-blah blah  1 blah-blah blah
      blah blah 2000
      blah blah 600
      ipv6 primary fc00:a:a::300
      ipv6 secondary fc00:a:a::400
      blah blah-blah blah-blah-blah-blah-blah blah
      blah blah-blahblah-blah-blah-blah-blah blah
      blah blah-blah-blah BLAH_BLAH_BLAH_BLAH
      blah-blah blah BLAH
      blah-blah blah 2000
    exit
```

I am trying to match the text `fc00:a:a::300` with `ipv6 primary` as the anchor while using the `xxxx` as a key.  I am trying to use a working regex pattern that matches all the possible `blah`s that would contain any character.  Any suggestions?

I've tried using `\s[\w+\-]\s+ipv6\s+dns primary\s+` but am not able to match the text.

Comment: what is your expected o/p ?

Comment: How does the regex that you already tried look like? Ah now I see, will add code formatting..

Comment: Actually just found a solution:
    .*
This seems to match anything between "xxxxx" and "ipv6 primary "

Comment: @ozn You want to get the `fc00:a:a::300` or everything before that? There's a difference!

Comment: I need it to match fc00:a:a::300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using something like this:

```
regexp -lineanchor -- {apn xxxxx.*?ipv6 primary\s*?([^\n]+)$} $text - match
```

You should get `fc00:a:a::300` in the variable `$match`.

`apn xxxxx` will match exactly that.

`.*?` will match any characters up to `ipv6 primary`.

`\s*?` will match any spaces

`([^\n]+)` will match non-newlines until... `$` (the end of line).

`-lineanchor` makes `$` match all end of lines.

[demo](http://codepad.org/nLdxvAIp)

---

If you don't want to match one that is outside of the `apn xxxxx ... exit`, then you could use something like this:

```
regexp -lineanchor -- {apn xxxxx(?:(?!exit).)*?ipv6 primary\s*?([^\n]+)$} $text - match
```

`(?:(?!exit).)*?` will match any character except `exit`.

[demo](http://codepad.org/T261LTHT)

Answer (score 0):

```
apn xxxx[\s\S]*?ipv6 primary (.*)
```

should do .

demo here: http://regex101.com/r/tB5tJ0

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. set your lengthy string in a variable as
   set a {....
          ....
          ....}
2. Apply this command
      regexp {.*ipv6\sprimary\s+(\S+)} $a t t1

The output for t1 will be as "fc00:a:a::300".